# Is the convex hull of a countable set a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

The convex hull of a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the smallest convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing $X$.  My question is, if $X$ is countable, then is the convex hull of $X$ necessarily a Borel set?

If not, does anyone know of a counterexample?

Comment: The convex hull is also the intersection of all half-spaces that contain it, by the [supporting hyperplane theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane)/

Comment: @logarithm Isn’t that only true of $X$ is closed?

Comment: Suppose $E=\{x_1,x_2,\dots \}.$ Let $E_n$ be the convex hull of $\{x_1,\dots, x_n \}.$ Isn't it true that the convex hull of $E$ is $\cup E_n?.$

Comment: By https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull) the ch of $X$ is the union of the closed  triangles whose vertices are in $X$.  Of which there are only countably many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes，it is Borel.

Define $\text{conv}_n(E)$ by
$x\in \text{conv}_n(E)$ iff $\exists a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\in E,\exists t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\in[0,1], \Sigma t_i=1$ such that $x=\Sigma_{i=1}^n t_ia_i$.

It is easily to seen that $\text{conv}_n(E)$ is Borel, so $\text{conv}(E)$ is Borel since
$\text{conv}_n(E)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\text{conv}_n(E)$
(Try to prove this equality,please note that the union is vonvex and contains $E$, or refer J. van Mill's book-infinite-Dimensional Topology, Page 7,Lemma 1.2.2)